# Accessing API through token from Auth0

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, auth0

I'm implementing Auth0 to use in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app with React frontend and haven't been able to make API calls using the token obtained from Auth0. I keep getting unauthorized error.

Here's the code in `ConfigureServices()` method in my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
  .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions => {
      jwtOptions.Authority = "https://myapp.auth0.com/";
      jwtOptions.Audience = "https://myapp.com/api/";
   });

   string domain = $"https://myapp.auth0.com/";
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
      options.AddPolicy("read:data", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:data", domain)));
   });

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();
```

I have the following to handle scope:

```
public class HasScopeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
   public string Issuer { get; }
   public string Scope { get; }

   public HasScopeRequirement(string scope, string issuer)
   {
       Scope = scope ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scope));
       Issuer = issuer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(issuer));
   }
}

public class HasScopeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasScopeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasScopeRequirement requirement)
    {
        // If user does not have the scope claim, get out of here
        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "scope" && c.Issuer == requirement.Issuer))
           return Task.CompletedTask;

        // Split the scopes string into an array
        var scopes = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "scope" && c.Issuer == requirement.Issuer).Value.Split(' ');

        // Succeed if the scope array contains the required scope
        if (scopes.Any(s => s == requirement.Scope))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Also, in the `Configure()` method, I have `app.UseAuthentication();`

Here's the code in my `auth0.js` service:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: 'myapp.auth0.com',
        clientID: 'client_id_copied_from_application_settings_on_auth0',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:49065/member/callback',
        audience: 'https://myapp.com/api/',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        scope: 'openid'
    });
```

My frontend is successfully obtaining `access_token`, `expires_at` and `id_token`. Using Postman, I make an API call to one of my API methods but I keep getting `401 Unauthorized` error. I'm posting a screen shot of what I'm seeing in Postman below. Looks like it doesn't like the audience.

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the plain text of the HTTP request that you are sending. It would be useful to look at your headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We at Auth0 put together a blog tutorial series on this using .Net Core 2.0 which might be helpful to track back on.

https://auth0.com/blog/developing-web-apps-with-asp-dot-net-core-2-dot-0-and-react-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article but I don't see in there that's different than what's in my code. One question: do I need `https://` preceding my domain? Currently my domain is `mycompanyname.auth0.com`. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Good practice would be to use `https://` - in addition you want to make sure the full callback URL is included

Comment: How do I update it? Do I need to delete my account and re-create it to change it?